# How would I make this method loop if a user would input a character other than 'r' or 'c'?

Tags: java

Say, a user would input 'e' so it would show an error dialog but how I loop it back if that would be the case?

```
 public static char readTypeOfConsumer(){
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    char typeCode='x';
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the type consumer< you may type r for 
   residential or c for commercial>:");
        typeCode = kbd.next().charAt(0);
        if (typeCode == 'r' || typeCode == 'R') {
            System.out.println("type: Residential");
        } else if (typeCode == 'c' || typeCode == 'C') {
            System.out.println("type: Commercial");
        }
    } while (typeCode == 'r' || typeCode == 'R' || typeCode == 'c'|| typeCode == 'C');

     return typeCode;
}
```

doing this method has not worked for me unfortunately

Comment: what's your exact problem?

Comment: typeCode is updated in the do statement on first iteration to whatever the first char of the entered user data is.

Comment: my problem would be it not looping, I basically just need to find out how it would loop. As mentioned the do while loop has not worked for me so I need a another approach on how it would loop

Comment: Why dont you create two or statement one would be your whole statement which you have mentioned in while and another one would be not equal to r and c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
public static char readTypeOfConsumer() {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean typeCodeInvalid = true;

    char typeCode;
    do {
        typeCodeInvalid = false;
        System.out.println(
                "Enter the type consumer< you may type r for  residential or c for commercial>:");
        typeCode = kbd.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        if (typeCode == 'r') {
            System.out.println("type: Residential");
        } else if (typeCode == 'c') {
            System.out.println("type: Commercial");
        } else {
            typeCodeInvalid = true;
        }

    } while (typeCodeInvalid);

    return typeCode;
}
```

---

I've added a `boolean` which has the value `false` when the input is accepted, there might be better ways to do this but I'm just going off of the code you've provided. It will just keep looping until `r` or `c` is entered.

I've also added `toLowerCase()` so you do not have to check if it's `c` or `C` but just `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try:

```
    public static char readTypeOfConsumer(){
   char typeCode='x';

  do {
    System.out.println("Enter the type consumer< you may type r for residential or c for commercial>:");
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    typeCode = kbd.next().charAt(0);
    if (typeCode == 'r' || typeCode == 'R') {
        System.out.println("type: Residential");
    } else if (typeCode == 'c' || typeCode == 'C') {
        System.out.println("type: Commercial");
    }
} while (typeCode == 'r' || typeCode == 'R' || typeCode == 'c'|| typeCode == 'C');

 return typeCode;
```

}
}

Comment: How is this supposed to make it work? You've only moved the `Scanner kbd` but not adjusted the `while` loop.